# Method of paralleling VFDs over DC bus bar

Tags: inverter, busbar

We have some VFD with considerable power output. There are some issues around stable operations. However we found out, that the layout is somehow special.

I added a single VFD, a simplified diagram with connection of bus bars follows...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7LcDG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

On the powerline side the VFD gets three phase AC. Each phase is dealed by a IGBT block, so there are three of them. Each IGBT block has a positive and negative output delivering DC voltage, all DC outputs are connected according to their polarity, otherwise it couldn't operate. At the DC output there's a first capacitor bank in parallel. After that a inductor is in series in the positive rail, Followed by a second capacitor in parallel (connecting the inductor output with the DC negative) again. Then another inductor follows in series with the negative rail and a third capacitor in parallel before DC power reaches the output stage delivering the three AC output phases.

So the capacitors and inductors are in a kind of double Z configuration.
The VFD is absolutely symmetrical with the exception of the middle capacitor connecting the neg. output of the input stage with the pos input of the output stage. The pos DC line as well as the neg DC line is separated by the inductors.

Of these complete VFD blocks there are four. Those are connected to each others as follows: They are paralleled at the 3-phase AC inputs, as well as at the 3-phase AC outputs for greater power. And then they are paralleled over a DC bus bar. The DC bus bar is tied to the ends of the middle capacitor of each VFD block. So the negative bus bar node is the negative output of the input stage and the positive bus bar node is the positive input of the output stage.

Is there a reason to connect it that way (1)? Considering the primary power flow direction is from input to output stage wouldn't it be wiser to connect the bus bar directly to the DC inputs of the output stage (2)?

I most likely never came to ask this if I hadn't found out that the schematic delivered for these VFDs shows variant (2), while the actual wiring is variant (1).

[image]

I'll transfer the image into native schematic later, if needed.

So the VFD blocks are connected via bus bar at -A and +B, while the schematic says the bus bar connects -B and +B.

Comment: Impossible to say without insight from the controller, and likely original designer.